# How to make new object and preserve Listeners from old object of the same type

Tags: java

I have class Flight with implemented PropertyChangeSupport as follows:

protected List changeListeners;

public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listenerToAdd){ ...}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listenerToRemove){ ... }

private  void notifyChangeListeners(String message){ ...}

...classic observer pattern. What I want to accomplish is creation of new Flight objects, but with preservation of existing PropertyChangeListeners. What look as simple task took me deep into multithreading and concurrency troubles, discovering also "lapsed listener problem".

This is my first "simple solution" that doesnt work:

```
public Flight newFlightWithOldListeners(List<Scans> scansList){
    Flight newFlight=new FlightImpl();
    newFlight.setScansList(scansList);
    newFlight.setExplorerManager(this.getExplorerManager());
    for (Iterator<PropertyChangeListener> iterator = this.getChangeListeners().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        PropertyChangeListener listener=iterator.next();
        newFlight.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        iterator.remove();
    }
    return newFlight;
}
```

I'm not getting any error, but this doesnt act as it should. All PropertyChangeListeneres remain linked to old Flight objects, and PropertyChangeEvents are fired before it should be fired.

Am I completely missed logic? This look as something that should be trivial?

Question is about design. Is this good design for creation of new objects with old PropertyChangeListeners?

Comment: What is the exact exception? What line of code threw this exception? The answer may be obvious but to be sure, we need more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly change the underlying collection while iterating on it or you will get `ConcurrentModificationException`. You should use iterator's `remove()` method instead.

Instead of

```
this.changeListeners.remove(iterator.next());
```

just do

```
iterator.remove()
```

As for the logic you should do

```
for (Iterator<PropertyChangeListener> iterator = this.getChangeListeners().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener   = (PropertyChangeListener )iterator.next();
    newFlight.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for iterator.remove(), this remove ConcurrentModificationException, but what I'm missing have to do with logic. Code doesnt act as it should. I am getting propertyChangeEvents from old FlightImpl object, and new object (newFlight) doesn't register PropertyChangeListeners. Maybe I should clone PropertyChangeListener from old object or something similar? There is have to be some simpler solution?

Comment: Have expanded the answer to add correct logic as well. You should not call `next()` two times in one iteration.

Comment: I edited code. I'm not getting any exception, but code doesn work. I'm missing some crucial!

Answer (score 0):

Am suspecting your getting problem because of `iterator` because your modifying (removing elements) `changeListers` after creating `iterator`. In most cases `iterator` wont allow us to change the `list` from outside. use `iterator.remove()` this will fix.